So we have heard!
When you want to say that you have come to know of a certain information from others, I have seen people first narrate what they have heard and then finally say something like, "so I have heard from others" which actually means that whatever they just said is all from others as such.
Is it proper English? When I google I get examples with a comma after "So" which means totally differs in meaning from what I looking for.
Eg: So, I have that she is not going to the event.
What I am looking for is the usage which could be put as follows in a conversation.
Eg: She is not going to the event. So I have heard from others.
Can someone explain if it a correct usage?

You are using "so" as a pronoun for that thing. So, it's different from "so" meaning therefore. You can also use the expression ironically: "Fast? Slow is very good, too. Or so I've heard."

It's perfectly correct. I would say that this sense of so means thus. The habit of starting a story with 'So' is a recent and, to me, peculiar usage.

@KateBunting: Even more so the habit of starting questions on Stack Exchange sites with So. I never had a problem with a stand-up comic starting his act (or the next "anecdotal segment") with So, because the context feels like I can assume an unspoken "I'm up here to entertain you with some funny stories, so [here goes...]". But when the first word of an ELL/ELU question is So, I always think Where's the antecedent referenced by so?

In so I have heard, the so is functioning adverbially as part of a description of the manner of the hearing. For comparison, the utterance

We can quit early for the day; the boss said so

can be paraphrased as

We can quit early for the day; the boss expressed himself in such a manner as to communicate that permission.

Here’s another example of the adverbial use of so. Suppose I were teaching someone a skill, showing them how to perform it. Then I might correct their first attempt by saying, “No, don’t hold it that way. Try it so,” and then immediately demonstrating the better grip. In that example, so can be paraphrased as in the manner I am about to demonstrate.

"She is not going to the event, or so I've heard."  I one way to put it.  I would say "I heard she isn't going to the event."
